# How can I repair the scroll ball on an older Mighty Mouse?

Tags: mouse

I have a Mighty Mouse that came with an iMac nearly four years ago, and the scroll ball won't turn anymore. Is it possible to clean that or do something to make it usable again?

Answer (score 5):

Try flipping the mouse upside down and rolling the trackball on a piece of paper, giving it an occasional tap to help dislodge any debris. Since the trackball is depressed while rolling , this helps debris escape from inside the housing. The paper will also help absorb any oil from your fingers that have collected on the ball that may allow debris to collect inside the roller mechanisms.

- The 'official' Apple fix is to first spray the paper with alcohol cleaner, then roll the ball over it. This has always worked for me, never had to take apart.

Answer (score 2):

This video tutorial entitled ["How To Clean An Apple Mighty Mouse Scroll Bar"](http://computer-hardware.wonderhowto.com/how-to/clean-apple-mighty-mouse-scroll-ball-217746/) may help.

Comment: I've never heard of someone taking apart a Mighty Mouse and having it remain in one piece without copious amounts of clue or tape, but this guys video actually does arrive at the part and proposes a valid solution to resolving the issue. Still, I would not attempt this unless you have a spare mouse and this is your last resort.

Comment: @RyanHollingsworth I whole-heartedly agree with you, but he does provide a sound solution to the issue at hand.

Comment: agreed. hopefully it works :) if not, the Magic Mouse is pretty awesome. I have to take breaks from it for the sake of it's small size is hard on my average (not small) hands and it gives me some carpel tunnel issues.

Comment: @RyanHollingsworth Ah what about changing to an ordinary mouse or using the Magic Trackpad instead ?

Comment: yeah i'm switching to my razer gaming mouse haha.. i may get the magic trackpad soon.. thanks for suggestions :)

Comment: @RyanHollingsworth Which Razer did you buy, i'm not an avid gamer, but they are supposed to be high quality. My current desktop mouse is currently approx 7 years old

Comment: i don't game much either but i like the Naga mouse with it's series of buttons available to your thumb. Got it super cheap on Woot.com

Comment: @RyanHollingsworth Nice.....only problem is i'm left handed.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem with multiple mice in the past before.  The roll on paper did work for a few weeks months (I usually applied a few drops of alcohol to the ball before doing it). But essentially when this problem starts, the mouse is going downhill and nothing much can be done about it (the problem will reoccur within shorter and shorter time).

I tried opening two of the mice which didn't respond to other solutions anymore, figuring I couldn't damage them any further because they were already useless anyway.  It worked with one with little damage to the case and putting it together with a few drops of glue.  The other, while managing to open it with little damage, failed to work afterwards because I damaged the insides of the scroll ball unit.

Answer (score 0):

The mouse you have is called a Mighty Mouse. There are various ways to clean it. See [this previous question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13580/how-do-i-clean-the-apple-mouse-so-that-it-can-scroll-down), for example.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend disassembly of the mouse and cleaning the track ball with ear swabs and alcohol

Answer (score 0):

I used all kind of tricks to clean my Mighty Mouse but at the end none of them was a long term solution, the track ball got stuck quite soon again, independently of how carefully I was with cleaning. I ended up with taking the mouse apart. That worked. You need a (very) small amount of glue to put it back again (if you are anal about the plastic ring underneath the mouse - I used my mouse for months without it because I didn't have any glue).

So, take your mouse apart and clean it. That is the only longterm solution.